# How to get to level 200 as a Bowmaster in Maplestory?

Tags: maplestory

I have a Bowmaster level 120 and I am trying to figure out the best ways to train my bowmaster so that he can become level 200, lately PQs are not doing it for me and I know quest can be long and tiresome is there another way I only have 1 1/2 hours to play a day!

Comment: "1 1/2 hours to play a day!" be prepared to either spend alot of money on 2x cards. also, knowing your _current level_ would help, and level of funding I suppose.

Comment: You said either but didn't write my other option... My character is level 120 and my budget would probably be about $40 a week @KevinL

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to delete it & wait for a burning event & create a new character, which will level 3 times as fast - plus, you get the Frozen equips set which should last you until 5th job.

If you don't want to do that, then Monster Park is the way to go. I generally use it from about level 120 to 180 or more. With 2 free runs a day, you can expect to average one level a day (more at level 120, fewer at higher levels).

Don't forget x2 - events in weekends, reward for Inferno Wold Den, Fairy brothers (+ Spirit Pendant), even cash shop if you are willing to pay.

Plus, the quickest way to get your Bowmaster to 200 might actually be to ignore it for  a while & burn a Mercedes for the Link Skill. It can give any other character +10/15/20% EXP at level 70/120/210. It's easy to burn one to level 150 in a full day, 190/200 in a week, but might tale a month to get to 210. However, you can give the link skill to another character & can change which one you give it o.

Comment: We are currently having the Neo event, with Tera Burning, which is 3 levels for every 1 until level 200. I made a Bowmaster in two days, for the great combination of link skill & legion skill. The event is still running, and will have two episodes where you can x3 burn 2 chars until 150 and 1 until 200. That's lot of great link & legion skills. If you don't aim for 210, then stop at 140 (120 for link, 140 for legion, with the next stops at 210 & 200). Please let us know how it tuns out.

Comment: OP asked 7 years ago and hasn't signed on since the day after they asked. I highly doubt they will return to let you know how it goes. Who knows if they even still play Maple Story...

Comment: Yes (+1), I noticed that after I posted. Still, we know how it turns out for me, if not for him. And, since I am a casual player, this is prolly how it would turn out for most people  these days. Two days to get to level 200 (some people do it in one). Maple has changed a ***looooot*** in 7 years :-/